# Equality in calculus

Tags: calculus

Show that  $\frac{ b - a} {1+b^2}< tan^{-1 }b - tan^{-1} a < \frac{b-a}{1+a^2}$ and hence deduce that $\frac{5\pi+4}{2} < tan^{-1}2 < \frac{\pi+2}{4}$

Comment: This is difficult to read. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Note that $\tan^{-1}b-\tan^{-1}a=\tan^{-1}\frac{b-a}{1+ab}$

Comment: @AbishankaSaha . So it's solvable by elementary trig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use that $$\frac{\arctan(b)-\arctan(a)}{b-a}=\frac{1}{1+\xi^2}$$ and $$\xi \in (a,b)$$